# Cannot run PhoneGap 1.0.0 app on Android 1.6

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to a run PhoneGap 1.0.0 app on the Android 1.6 emulator. I get the following error:

> Could not find method `android.webkit.WebSettings.setDatabaseEnabled`, referenced from method `com.phonegap.DroidGap.init`

It seems that Android 1.6 has no database support in its browser. My application doesn't need local database, however I don't find where should I disable this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhoneGap 1.0 deprecates Android 1.x support. Use an older PhoneGap version or newer Android. More at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/cZANbEf51uY

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in AndroidManifest.xml maybe.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is only line close to sql :)